# Display values from External API response

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm making a successful call to an API with Phoenix. But I'm struggling to take the response and display it the way that I'd like. Here is my raw response:

#### REPONSE:

```
%{"date" => "2016-11-22", "games" => [%{"away" => %{"alias" => "POR", "id" => "583ed056-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c", "name" => "Portland Trail Blazers"}, "away_points" => 103, "broadcast" => %{"network" => "MSG", "satellite" => "634"}, "coverage" => "full", "home" => %{"alias" => "NYK", "id" => "583ec70e-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c", "name" => "New York Knicks"}, "home_points" => 107, "id" => "c58e2153-95f4-46b5-b10d-f89d342e4f9c", "scheduled" => "2016-11-23T00:30:00+00:00", "status" => "closed", "venue" => %{"address" => "Four Pennsylvania Plaza", "capacity" => 19812, "city" => "New York", "country" => "USA", "id" => "583152aa-de75-5bea-ac92-ac5b8a51f9f9", "name" => "Madison Square Garden", "state" => "NY", "zip" => "10001"}}, %{"away" => %{"alias" => "NOP", "id" => "583ecc9a-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c", "name" => "New Orleans Pelicans"}, "away_points" => 112, "broadcast" => %{"network" => "NBA TV", "satellite" => "216"}, "coverage" => "full", "home" => %{"alias" => "ATL", "id" => "583ecb8f-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c", "name" => "Atlanta Hawks"}, "home_points" => 94, "id" => "fdae2288-e112-4bee-a028-16b761818d2f", "scheduled" => "2016-11-23T00:30:00+00:00", "status" => "closed", "venue" => %{"address" => "One Philips Drive", "capacity" => 18118, "city" => "Atlanta", "country" => "USA", "id" => "fd21f639-8a47-51ac-a5dd-590629d445cf", "name" => "Philips Arena", "state" => "GA", "zip" => "30303"}}, %{"away" => %{"alias" => "CHI", "id" => "583ec5fd-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c", "name" => "Chicago Bulls"}, "away_points" => 107, "broadcast" => %{"network" => "ALT", "satellite" => "681"}, "coverage" => "full", "home" => %{"alias" => "DEN", "id" => "583ed102-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c", "name" => "Denver Nuggets"}, "home_points" => 110, "id" => "cd1bace5-3cdd-46b4-b175-7475bebcf050", "scheduled" => "2016-11-23T02:00:00+00:00", "status" => "closed", "venue" => %{"address" => "1000 Chopper Circle", "capacity" => 19155, "city" => "Denver", "country" => "USA", "id" => "1a28ef88-76c9-5bcc-b4ee-51d30ca98f4f", "name" => "Pepsi Center", "state" => "CO", "zip" => "80204"}}, %{"away" => %{"alias" => "OKC", "id" => "583ecfff-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c", "name" => "Oklahoma City Thunder"}, "away_points" => 109, "broadcast" => %{"network" => "NBA TV", "satellite" => "216"}, "coverage" => "full", "home" => %{"alias" => "LAL", "id" => "583ecae2-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c", "name" => "Los Angeles Lakers"}, "home_points" => 111, "id" => "ed4bf9d1-3d12-4398-9340-6ba9a56c5e4a", "scheduled" => "2016-11-23T03:30:00+00:00", "status" => "closed", "venue" => %{"address" => "1111 S. Figueroa St.", "capacity" => 19060, "city" => "Los Angeles", "country" => "USA", "id" => "792ec100-691e-5e16-8ef8-79b2b6ee38ba", "name" => "Staples Center", "state" => "CA", "zip" => "90015"}}], "league" => %{"alias" => "NBA", "id" => "4353138d-4c22-4396-95d8-5f587d2df25c", "name" => "NBA"}}
```

#### Template

```
<%= for schedule <- @schedule do  %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= schedule.games %></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

#### Error:

```
argument error
```

Controller:

```
  def list_schedules(conn, params) do
    date = build_date(params["list_schedules"]["date"])

    with {:ok, schedule} <- GameSchedules.get_schedule(date) do
     render(conn, "index.html", schedule: schedule)
    end
  end
```

#### GamesSchedules

```
  def get_schedule(date) do
    url = url_from_date(date)

    case HTTPoison.get(url) do
    {:ok, %{status_code: 200, body: body}} ->
      {:ok, Poison.decode!(body)}
    {:ok, %{status_code: 404}} ->
      {:error, :not_found}
    {:error, _err} ->
      {:error, :internal_server_error}
    end
  end

  defp url_from_date(date) do
    "https://api.sportradar.us/nba/trial/v4/en/games/#{date}/schedule.json?api_key=zknxtpcs4d9j3yw93e5aqkjk"
  end
```

#### ERROR STACKTRACE:

[image]

How can I take the response and just display what I want from it in the view?

I want to iterate through the games and return the names of the teams that played on a given night.

Comment: Can you post the code of `GameSchedules.get_schedule` and the full error message including the stack trace?

Comment: @Dogbert updated.

Comment: The API doesn't return a list, it returns a map, which is why `schedule.games` doesn't work inside `for`. Not sure what you want to print in the template, but remove the `for` and add `<%= inspect(@schedule["games"]) %>`?

Comment: Yea, that wraps what I had an array. I want to look within the "games" array and pull out the home team name and away team name from the response and display that to the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@schedule` here is a map, not a list. You should iterate over `@schedule["games"]` if you want to print info about each game. Here's how to print the Home and Away teams' names in two `<td>` inside a `<tr>`:

```
<%= for game <- @schedule["games"] do  %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= game["away"]["name"] %></td>
    <td><%= game["home"]["name"] %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks @dogbert. Yea, that makes a lot of sense